# Wordpress Multisite local: wp-login.php refreshes on login Chrome Browser

Tags: multisite, login, localhost, google-chrome

I just set up Wordpress Multisite on my local machine following [this](http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-subdomains-mamp/) tutorial. When I try to login to the admin using Google Chrome, the page just refreshes. I've tried Firefox, and I'm able to login and use Wordpress Multisite normally and access the dashboard. I've tried clearing my cache, and using incognito mode in Google Chrome, to make sure that it wasn't a caching issue. Here are the steps I take to login:

1. I navigate to `http://dev-server/wp-admin`
2. I'm redirected to `http://dev-server/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-server%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`
3. I enter my username and password, then click 'Log in'
4. I'm redirected to `http://m1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev-server%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

I've also added to my wp-config.php as referenced [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42539/mamp-wordpress-site-works-but-cannot-login):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://dev-server');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://dev-server');
```

Is there anything else I can try? I'd like to be able to use both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Does adding [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) tell you anything?

Comment: No, I still get the same result. Nothing outputs on the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I installed [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin, set the mapping my to home ip, 127.0.0.1, then added my site to domains with the domain name I wanted. The domain name in domains must match the site domain. Once all of that was done, I made sure the domain was also mapped in my hosts file.

I hope this helps anyone else that runs into this issue.

Comment: It solved my problem.